# Executing Windows Service (*.exe) from Asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have created Windows Service and Installed `.exe` file in my system. I am able to run this Service from `Service` control on windows 10.

I am running same service from ASP.NET web application. Service gets started but I want to call `protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)` method while calling from web Application.

I am getting error of

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceProcess.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot control ServiceName service on computer '.'.
```

Code written on web page to call windows service is as -

```
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName");
            if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running && sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(60000);
                sc.Start();
                sc.ExecuteCommand(CommandId);
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            }
```

Can anybody help to get the cause of this issue?

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with the computer name on that service call, or perhaps a permissions issue.

Comment: Have you checked [these things](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b2cef9a-1e73-4857-9256-d299eaaddf55/cannot-control-ltservice-namegt-service-on-computer?forum=csharpgeneral)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, It seems like that. But I am not understanding how to give Computer name or How to give permissions. And another thing is, if its a permission issue then how service is getting started without any permission.

Comment: Really seems like you should be using bus messages or Web API or Nancy or something to communicate with your service, rather than going through the ServiceController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code running the web page does not have the administrator privileges to control a service on that machine.

You would have to configure your app pool to run under an administrative account. that might not be a good idea from a security point of view.

If you don't want to run your web app with administrative privileges, you could consider hosting your own listener in your windows service that only needs a username/password or maybe no authentication at all because you pick a variant that is only available to localhost. WCF might be a good option for this or maybe ASP.NET if you are more familiar with that.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend WCF unless you're using SOAP (which actually might be a reasonable approach).

Comment: I was thinking named pipes as it's local machine only. But any technology to connect two processes should work.